# expected primary-expression before ',' token

Tags: c++, expected-exception

Im currently getting the error:

```
kernel.c++:76:21: error: expected primary-expression before ',' token
     Task task1(&gdt , taskA);
                     ^
kernel.c++:77:21: error: expected primary-expression before ',' token
     Task task2(&gdt , taskB);
```

Not sure why this is happening here is the code of my kernel.c++ simplified:

```
void taskA();
void taskB();

extern "C" void kernelMain
        (
            /*arguments...*/
        )


{
       gdt gt;

       TaskManager taskManager;
       Task task1(&gdt , taskA);
       Task task2(&gdt , taskB);
       taskManager.AddTask(&task1);
       taskManager.AddTask(&task2);
}

void taskA()
{
    while(true)
        printf("A");
}


void taskB()
{
    while(true)
        printf("B");
}
```

If you want to see my actual kernel code : https://github.com/amanuel2/OS_Mirror/blob/master/kernel.c%2B%2B .. Any Help

Here is my task.h simplified:

```
class Task
{
          friend class TaskManager;
              private:
                  uint8_t stack[4096]; // 4 KiB
                  CPUState* cpustate;
              public:


              Task(gdt *GlobalDescriptorTable, void entrypoint());
              ~Task();
    };


    class TaskManager
    {
            private:
                Task* tasks[256];
                uint32_t num_task;
                uint32_t current_task;
            public:
                TaskManager();
                ~TaskManager();
                bool AddTask(Task* task);
                CPUState* Schedule(CPUState* cpustate);
    };
```

If you want to see whole code for task.h here it is : https://github.com/amanuel2/OS_Mirror/blob/master/task.h ..

and finally minimized task.c++:

```
Task::Task(gdt *GlobalDescriptorTable, void entrypoint())
{
 /*Stuff Happenes Here.. But i Minimized it*/
}
```

If you want to see the actual task.c++ here it is : https://github.com/amanuel2/OS_Mirror/blob/master/task.c%2B%2B .. I dont understand why i get that error. Any Help Would be greatly appreciated thankyou.

Comment: Isn't `gdt` a type? I think you want `&gt` when you create `task1` and `task2` or was that a typo?

Comment: suggest using different naming convensions for types than for variables

Comment: Yeah sorry @TimothyMurphy .. my fault . Its solved now. Thankyou , should i delete this question?

Comment: have voted to close as a typo. You could delete if you want

Comment: @M.M ill just vote to close it.. Ok thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is probably in these two lines:

```
Task task1(&gdt , taskA);
Task task2(&gdt , taskB);
```

It should be

```
Task task1(&gt , taskA);
Task task2(&gt , taskB);
```

You should change your type names and variable names so they don't look alike that much so as to avoid these kind of errors.